# How to access DirecroryEntry with C#?

Tags: c#, active-directory

How can I access through DirectoryEntry Class via C#. I need to create an application that retrieve`s and update`s user data in Active Directory

Comment: A simple google search gives tons of info about the subject, [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C) for example. You should come here only with specific questions

Comment: thanks for your assumption;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access in Directory Entry you need to add those 2 lines:

```
Namespace:   System.DirectoryServices
Assembly:  System.DirectoryServices (in System.DirectoryServices.dll)
```

The DirectoryEntry class encapsulates a node or object in the Active Directory Domain Services hierarchy

```
Inheritance Hierarchy
  System.Object
   System.MarshalByRefObject
    System.ComponentModel.Component
     System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
```

The syntax is as follows:

```
[DSDescriptionAttribute("DirectoryEntryDesc")]
[DirectoryServicesPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, 
Unrestricted = true)]
[EnvironmentPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)]
[SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Assert, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
public class DirectoryEntry : Component`
```

For more infomation [click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate this so much!